# VBA Macro help need for Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I hope this will make sense,

I have found this script that if a letter or number is in one cell it will input a value in the another cell

I was wondering how I could add multiple rules to this.At the moment if C or 9 is entered in a cell then it produces the sentence "word here will show up"

I want it to show up in a different cell not the adjacent one, and also I want to be able to add different letter to the list to output different values.

EG

Cell Has This in Column A               Output when Macro runs in Column E

C or 9                                                                                        "Word0"

HELLO OR GOODBYE                                                 "Word1"

Pink or Yellow                                                                           "Word2"

Etc,
 Any help would be great and appreciated as I am very new to VB and Macros.

The code below only does C or 9 I thought I could just add .Forumula to the code below to add more words but it didn't work

```
Sub CheckValues()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)
        .Formula = "=IF(MIN(FIND({""C"",9},A2&""C9""))<=LEN(A2),""Word0"","""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: stucharo's answer below is better than what I was going to share, but you may be interested to know that I have never had success applying a formula to a range. I think it can apply to individual cells only. To apply it to an entire range, use a `For Each (Range variable) in (Range Variable)` loop.

Comment: You cannot add addition two-line routines like you have above because you are overwriting the value in A2 and cannot expect to keep reevaluating the original value once you have overwritten it. The formula you are stuffing into A2 is also a circular reference so its a bit of a mystery why it is working at all. While the [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) could be used to determine the result of the formula, the method is clunky and the Select Case ... End Select is a much better fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going for a VBA approach then there's no real need to use `.Formula`.  VBA has a `Select Case` construct that lets you evaluate an expression and carry out a bunch of options based on the outcome of the expression.

Try this:

```
Sub CheckValues()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim startRow As Integer
    startRow = 2
    Dim endRow As Integer
    endRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).row

    Dim row As Integer
    Dim word As String

    For row = startRow To endRow

        Select Case Split(Cells(row, 1).Value, " ")(0)

            Case "C", "9"
                word = "Word0"
            Case "HELLO", "GOODBYE"
                word = "Word1"
            Case "Pink", "Yellow"
                word = "Word2"
            Case Else
                word = ""

        End Select

        Cells(row, 5).Value = word

    Next row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

As you add more options for column a, you only need to repeat the `Case *expression*` pattern.

Comment: The question is why three nested if statements won't work XD

Comment: @findwindow Using Select Case is somewhat cleaner, because it only declares the testing variable once. This makes it easier to read (once you are familiar with the construct), and also saves a bit of processing power because the formula is calculated once, then stored, and referred to wihtout being evaluated multiple times. Dozens of ways to skin the cat...

Comment: @findwindow very good, although If we're being pedantic there ony was a statement that the code wouldn't work.  The question was how to add multiple rules and a `Select Case` is by far the easiest.  Plus trying to nest those `If`'s over any array length was a headache I couldn't bring myself to attempt :P

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Ahhh, the pros have a grasp of how architecture affects processing power ^_^;

Comment: @stucharo Yours is definitely better for longevity ^_^

Comment: @stucharo Thank you , it works perfectly but if I wanted to select just the first word in a sentence how would I do that? Eg if Hello I am Bob, and it realises that the word Hello is the first word in the sentence,  and then returns the word value in the Macro.

Comment: @PhpNewbie have a look at the `Split()` function.  It divdes a string into an array of strings based on a delimiter.  You can then pick the substring you want based on the index of the array.

Comment: @stucharo that is way beyond my ability with vba I've only started to use it 2 days ago

Comment: @PhpNewbie that's ok, everyone has to start somewhere :) I've edited my answer to include the `Split()` function.  The number in brackets following the function accesses that index of the array returned (arrays start at index 0 by default in VBA).

You should try and familiarise yourself with the MSDN reference.  It's a bit of a godsend sometimes.  The `Split()` function is described here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @stucharo You are amazing!! Thank you so much

Comment: @stucharo sorry to be a pain in the bum, if I wanted to use the above for football teams locations in the same area how would I do it, eg Cardiff City vs Manchester United or Newport County vs Everton = Wales. is there a way for it to read everything before the vs I have tried changing the delimiter but it didn't work. I am trying to spilt teams into certain area of the country, so would need it to read the first team then output the region its in, eg wales, surrey, kent, cardiff, etc Thank you for all your help already, and I know its asking alot to help me again, but I have tried for 5 days.

Comment: @PhpNewbie try changing the delimiter from `" "` to `" vs "`.  Index `(0)` of the reulting array should now be the home team and you can select cases based on that

Comment: @stucharo thank you fro responding, I have tried the following; `Select Case Split(Cells(row, 3).Value, "vs")(0)` and 'Select Case Split(Cells(row, 3).Value, "vs").index(0)' and Select Case Split(Cells(row, 3).Value, "vs".index(0)) all of them throw up an error apart from the first one that doesn't throw up any error, but doesn't output anything. Sorry once again, and thank you for all your help, I am trying to learn, but I learn by seeing something working and then I reverse engineer it (if that makes sense.

Comment: @PhpNewbie have you encountered the Immediate Window yet?  If not, hit Ctrl+G in the VBE and it should pop up at the bottom.  You can enter expressions directly (starting with a '?' character) or output data using `Debug.Print` statements.  You should try placing `Debug.Print Cells(row,3).Value` on the line preceding the `Select Case...` and place a breakpoint on the `Select Case....` line.  This will print out what's being read by the `Cells()` property and let you make sure you're getting what you expect

Comment: @stucharo this is the output I get                                                                       
`cardiff city v me
Brighton and Hove Albion v hove
Undy Athletic v New Port County
Alfreton Town v Derby County
Colwyn Bay v Wrexham`

Comment: @PhpNewbie in that case using `" vs "` as a delimiter will never work.....the teams are split by `" v "`.  Try using that instead......`Select Case Split(Cells(row, 3).Value, " v ")(0)`.  If the delimiter isn't found then the `Split()` function returns a single element array containing the entire string in the only element so it's unlikely that it would have matched any of your `Select Case`'s.

Comment: @stucharo, worked it out, totally my stupidity, I was using "v" instead of using the spaces so now I use  " v " as the delimiter and it works, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84726/discussion-between-php-newbie-and-stucharo).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just amend your existing formula and do it without loops:

```
Sub SO()

With Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(, 3)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(""Word""&ROUNDDOWN((MATCH(LEFT(RC[-3],SEARCH("" "",RC[-3])-1),{""C"",""9"",""HELLO"",""GOODBYE"",""Pink"",""Yellow""},0)/2)-0.1,0),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```